# keeping position fixed div over other position relative divs

Tags: html, css

I have some facebook style header div which is position:fixed.
So all the rest of the page when I scroll it goes under this header.

But now I made one div on that page position:relative and now it goes over header when I scroll it. Is there any way out of this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive you ought to check `z-index` of your *facebook style header div* and make sure that the relative, new one has a z-index lower that the header.

**Additional question:**

Does that relative div contain any media? Like flash or movie etc? That may also cause the content to be on top of other content in some browsers.

Comment: For a flash you can use this: `<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>`it will make flash box appear under other z-indexed elements. For video I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use position:absolute; with z-index:10000; (bigger than page's z-index)

Comment: can u show me example ?    headers css position:fixed. problemed divs css position:relative.   Now what must be changed to what ?

Comment: <div style="position:fixed; z-index:1000;">

but you better use javascript instead of position:fixed;, position:fixed works buggy in different browsers.

to do it in javascript you should determine scrollTop and set your header top position accordingly.